# Determining complex eigenvalues problem

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Im solving the eigenvalue for my Matrix A with eigenvalue: $2i$

```
-2i     0  2
  0  2-2i  0
 -2     0 -2i
```

This reduces to:

```
-2i     0  2
  0     1  0
  0     0  0
```

Thus $x_3$ is free, i know the answer is: $v= (1,0,i)^T$, I just don't know how they got to that answer, i try something like this: $-2i = -2x_3$ & $x_2 = 0$ and then I get $(1/i,0,1)^T$. Is this wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a given eigenvalue, any multiple of an eigenvector is an eigenvector.

Answering your concrete question, they obtained that answer by taking $x_3=i$, $x_2=0$, $x_1=2x_3/(2i)=2i/2i=1$.

Comment: Thus my version of the eigenvector is also correct?

Comment: Yes. Any choice of $x_3$, $x_2=0$, and $x_1=2x_3/(2i)$ will give you an eigenvector.